# ¿Por que el al imprimir un dato dado por el usuario no se muestran los acentos?

Tags: c++

¡Hola comunidad! Estoy tomando unos cursos de C++ para principiantes y el maestro nos dijo que al imprimir una sentencia con acentos, estos no se muestran naturalmente, por lo cual dijo que usáramos la biblioteca #include <locale.h> lo cual, en efecto, permite que se muestre el mensaje "¿Cómo te llamas?" correctamente, pero al introducir un dato con cin y después imprimirlo, los acentos siguen sin mostrarse. ¿Cómo puede arreglarse?

```
//Pedir datos al usuario y mostrarlos

#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    
    string nombre;
    cout<<"¿Cómo te llamas?"<<endl;
    cin>>nombre;
    cout<<"Hola "<<nombre<<",un gusto conocerte."<<endl;
}
```

[image: Al principio se muestran correctamente las palabras con acento, pero después ya no]

Comment: Probé tu código tuve ningún problema, (Linux Mint) , chequea las librerias de tu S.O. [imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrqQE.png)

Answer (score 3):

La consola de Windows es complicada en C++.

La mejor solución que encontré es usar `_setmode()` para `stdin` y `stdout` con `_O_U16TEXT` o `_O_WTEXT`, usar las versiones `wide` de todo lo que tenga que  ver con texto y guardar tu código en codificación UTF-16 (le o be, cualquiera funciona). Aquí un ejemplo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h> // _setmode
#include <fcntl.h> // _O_WTEXT y _O_U16TEXT

using namespace std;

int main() {

    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_WTEXT);

    // Como puedes ver son todos iguales solo que con una w al comienzo
    wstring nombre = L"";
    wcout << "¿Cómo te llamas?" << endl;
    wcin >> nombre;
    wcout << "Hola " << nombre << ", un gusto conocerte." << endl;
}
```

Respuesta basada en [esta otra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12015918).

**Actualización**

Una alternativa es usar las funciones propias de Windows. Puede ser un poco engorroso pero funciona. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    HANDLE outHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE inHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    const WCHAR * text = L"¿Cómo te llamas?\n";
    DWORD textLength = wcslen(text);

    WriteConsoleW(outHandle, text, textLength, 0, NULL);

    WCHAR buffer[1000] = L"\0";
    size_t bufferSize = sizeof buffer / sizeof *buffer;
    DWORD leido = 0;

    ReadConsoleW(inHandle, buffer, 20, &leido, NULL);
       
    wstring name = buffer;
    // Esto es para quitar el salto de línea
    int endLine = wcscspn(name.c_str(), L"\r\n");
    if (endLine >= 0)
        name.erase(endLine, 2);
    
    const WCHAR * saludo = L"Hola %s, un gusto conocerte.\n";
    DWORD saludoLen = wcslen(saludo);

    // Reiniciamos el buffer
    wmemset(buffer, L'\0', bufferSize);

    // Como printf, solo que para caracteres de tipo wide y lo guardamos en una variable en lugar de imprimirlo
    swprintf(buffer, bufferSize, saludo, name.c_str());

    wstring sSaludo = buffer;

    WriteConsoleW(outHandle, sSaludo.c_str(), sSaludo.size(), 0, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

El único problema de este método es que, al menos en mi computadora, no se imprimen bien los caracteres escritos en el código si usas codificación UTF-8. Literalmente funciona con cualquier otro formato que no sea ese. Irónicamente sí funciona con UTF-8 con BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Te faltó especificar el idioma. Añade el idioma español a setlocale
Quedaría así
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Spanish");